# zdump doesn't display expected information

Tags: linux, timezone

I am trying to configure the time zone of a server (Ubuntu 14.04.4), however the zdump command does not show the expected information like :

```
America/Santiago  Sun Apr 26 02:59:59 2015 UTC = Sat Apr 25 23:59:59 2015 CLST isdst=1 gmtoff=-10800
```

the command zdump shows:

```
zeusdevel@zeus2:~$ zdump -v /etc/localhost

/etc/localhost  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
/etc/localhost  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
/etc/localhost  9223372036854689407 = NULL
/etc/localhost  9223372036854775807 = NULL
```

However

```
zeusdevel@zeus2:~$  zdump Chile
Chile  Tue Apr 26 13:23:20 2016 Chile
```

and

```
zeusdevel@zeus2:~$ zdump -v
```

shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behaviour.

I believe what you mean is:

```
zdump -v /etc/localtime
```

localhost and localtime are two complete different things, although both start with local... =)

Answer (score -1):

`zdump` does not take path names as argument but rather time zone names.

If you use `zdump` the documented way, it is expected to work as documented.